# On a database level, what is the difference between [Django] OneToOneFiled and ForeignKey(Model, unique = True)

Tags: database, django

Both seems to be generating `integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES` databaase columns.

Edit: My question is only about at the database level. (Not in the Django ORM.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForeignKey` fields should be used for 1 to n relationships and `OneToOneField` should be used to 1 to 1 relationships.

On database level, the foreign key is unique for OneToOneFields and that's not the case for ForeignKeys.

Comment: With `ForeignKey(Model, unique = True)` the FK obviously is unique, so  are you saying that there is no diff?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had not noticed that on question's title. I think there's no difference indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is on the official [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield).

Basically, the difference is that when you try to access the ForeignKey from your object, you'll get another object, and not a queryset as you would in the ForeignKey.

From the docs:

> class OneToOneField(othermodel[, parent_link=False, **options])
>
> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True, but the "reverse" side of the relation will directly return a single object.

Comment: Flavio: Thanks for the link. However my question is is there **any** difference `On a database level`.

Comment: @uswaretech as far as the documentation goes, there is no difference in the database level.